# how to consume a kafka topic from a specific offset?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

recently I am using kafka,
I have a topic and I am using the following code to consume

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name", groupId =  "_id" , id = "pro", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory") 
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record, Acknowledgment ack) {            
        kafkaService.proccessorConsumer(record);
        ack.acknowledge();

    }
```

every thing works fine, but I need to handle a situation where if the service stopped for any reason, then started I want to continue consuming  from the last message that has processed, I do understand that the acknowledgment help with this, but for the sake of certainty I saved the last consumed offset somewhere.
my question is how I could use that offset to start consuming the topic from it.

Comment: "saved the last consumed offset somewhere"? Such as? Offsets are already stored in Kafka. That's what ack-ing does. When the consumer restarts, it'll already go to that offset for the consumer group (`groupId`)

Answer (score 0):

As @OneCricketeer indicates, what you are trying to achieve is the default behaviour of the Kafka consumer, if you haven't disabled automatic commit.

You can check this by describing your consumer group using the consumer id as follows, just check that the offset of your consumer is the same as the one you have stored elsewhere.

```
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group-id
```